# Rotate and translate a line so that it passes through two given points

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, 3d, rotations

I have 2 point and a line segment in 2d space. The line only rotates and translates using its mid point.

How do I calculate the translation and rotation required for the line to be touching the 2 points with center in the middle?

I know the initial state of the line, so calculating translation is easy 
$$
(x',y') = \frac{p_1+p_2}{2} -[\text{line center}]
$$
Can you please tell me how to calculate the rotation?

Thanks!

Comment: If you're rotating a line segment, then the segment might not be long enough to touch both points.  Can we assume that this won't be an issue?  Also, by "calculating the rotation", do you mean "finding the necessary angle of rotation"?

Comment: yes the line can be perceived as of infinite length. i said segment just to denote that there is a center. yes, angle of rotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes down to the following: we want to rotate the line so that it is parallel to the other segment.  Once we have this, the translation will ensure that the lines overlap (since they both intersect and have the same slope).

In order to find the necessary angle of rotation, find the angles (relative to the $x$-axis) at which the starting line and the target line, then take the difference.  If $m_1$ and $m_2$ are the respective slopes of the starting line and the target line, then the angle of rotation necessary is 
$$
\theta = \tan^{-1}(m_2) - \tan^{-1}(m_1)
$$

Comment: and slope would be dy/dx?

Comment: also tan-1 is same as arctan in terms of c++ or similar?

Comment: @AstaLabista more simply, it's $\frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2 - x_1}$.  If that's what you meant, then yes.  Keep in mind that depending on which $\tan^{-1}$ you use, $\theta$ might be off by $180^\circ$.  That's all right though; if you rotate a line $180^\circ$ around its midpoint, you end up with the same line.

Comment: Long story short: any arctan (including c++'s) will work perfectly well for your purposes

Comment: Keep in mind that vertical lines are problematic when finding slope, so you may have to consider that as a special case.

Comment: @AstaLabista protip: try `${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$`.  And you're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Let $a$ be the distance from the center point to one of the given points (say p1).  Let $b$ be the distance from the center point to one end of the line segment 
Let $c$ be the distance from p1 to the same end of the line segment.
Use the Law of Cosines $c^2=a^2+b^2-2ab\cos{\theta}$ and solve for $\theta$.

Comment: Can this be trimmed if we assume the line is parallel to one axis? something like finding the angle the 2 points make against the axis.

Comment: Yes, if the line is parallel to the axis, it would work.